# Is there any tool like MaintainJ for IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, reverse-engineering, sequence-diagram

I just tested MaintainJ Eclipse plugin and I find it very useful for reverse engineering sequence diagrams.
However, I use IntelliJ in my projects so I was just wondering either a similar plugin exists for my favourite IDE.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty old post, but this seems like a common question. So...

Check http://maintainj.com/userGuide.jsp?param=faq#eclipseNeeded for details.

In short, MaintainJ needs the free Eclipse version to view the sequence diagrams. But the call trace files can be generated without Eclipse. So you can generate the call trace files and then download the free Eclipse and view the sequence diagrams in Eclipse.